# Fullcalendar half working in firefox, works perfectly in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, fullcalendar

I have a site: [Play Date](http://www.chrisgregori.co.uk/playdate)  which uses a PHP script to pull data from an API, format it into JSON data which is then fed into FullCalendar.

It works great in Chrome, but other browsers don't handle it so great. Firefox manages to display the data from October onwards but it won't work before that..

Any ideas why?

Comment: Do you have some code to show us, or a jsFiddle? Which version of FullCalendar, of jQuery, of Firefox... ?

Comment: @Slyvain The latest Firefox (31 I think), 2.1 jQuery, and 1.64 FullCalendar. I just don't understand why it loads some months but not others. The code is identical, and the data format is the same.

Comment: Have you tried updating FullCalendar with the version 2.0 ?

Comment: I didn't realise that was out. I'll try it.

Comment: @Slyvain I replaced the file, now I get:
Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined js/fullcalendar.min.js:6
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: You probably didn't import all files from the FullCalendar package. In the directory full-calendar-2.0.x there is also a directory "lib", in it you'll find moment.min.js which is what you're missing I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the grid value given none for -moz-user-select

```
<div class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid" style="position: relative; -moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on">
```